# Performance of self.view for NSCollectionViewItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm looking at using an NSCollectionView for a photo library application, which will allow browsing of 10,000+ images.  I'm not sure if NSCollectionView is the best thing for this, or if I should be looking at other methods, so feel free to throw your 2 cents in if you have an opinion.

Anyway, in the (custom) class holding the NSCollectionViewItem, when a specific bound value is updated, I call a method on the item's view.

Problem is, just accessing [self view] is taking an exorbitant amount of time.  This was demonstrated by breaking the call to [self view] into another method and running instrumentation over it.  The following method

```
- (NSBox*)getBox {
    return (NSBox*)[self view];
}
```

takes about 100 times more processing time that any other single method.  Yes, it's called many times, but if I change to return self, rather than self.view, the getBox method doesn't even appear in the processing list.

Any ideas on why this should be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Image Kit's [`IKImageBrowserView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html), which is basically an iPhoto-like image browser?

There's the [ImageKitDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageKitDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004371) and [ImageBrowser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003997) sample projects.

Regarding the performance issue with `[self view]`, it might be that the collection view is being loaded lazily from the nib each time, and this call to `[self view]` is what's causing another instance to be instantiated from memory or from disk. While I haven't used `NSCollectionView` myself, my gut feeling is that there's probably going to be a greater overhead with numerous `NSView`s compared to `IKImageBrowserView` which uses the standard coupling of an `NSView` with an `NSCell`-like reusable drawing mechanism to help improve performance.

See [Avoid the Overuse of Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH11-112116):

> "A good example of when to use custom
>   objects is a photo browser that
>   displays thumbnail images of hundreds
>   or even thousands of photos. Wrapping
>   each photo in an `NSView` instance would
>   both be prohibitively expensive and
>   inefficient. Instead, you would be
>   better off by creating a lightweight
>   class to manage one or more photos and
>   a custom view to manage that
>   lightweight class."

(In many places, a single `NSView` subclass will re-use an `NSCell` subclass to help implement the drawing of its contents. In this respect, the `NSCell` basically acts as a little "drawing machine").

Comment: Thanks for the help, that makes a lot of sense.